# Boxplots of four variables in the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, iris-dataset

I would like to make four boxplots side-by-side using ggplot2, but I am struggling to find an explanation that suits my purposes.

I am using the well-known **Iris** dataset, and I simply want to make a chart that has boxplots of the values for sepal.length, sepal.width, petal.length, and petal.width all next to one another. These are all numerical values.

I feel like this should be really straightforward but I am struggling to figure this one out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This reminds me of one of my very first questions: [Do I really need to reshape this wide data to use ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7910594/903061). The answer, essentially, is yes: ggplot works really well with long data, and if your data is wide, your first step is to make it long. `tidyr::pivot_longer` is a good tool for that job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a one-liner using `reshape2::melt`

```r
ggplot(reshape2::melt(iris), aes(variable, value, fill = variable)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! I just discovered reshape2 recently and am still learning the lingo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The approach would be to selecting the numeric variables and with `tidyverse` functions reshape to long in order to sketch the desired plot. You can use `facet_wrap()` in order to create a matrix style plot or avoid it to have only one plot. Here the code (Two options):

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
data("iris")
#Code
iris %>% select(-Species) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scale='free')
```

Output:

[image]

Or if you want all the data in one plot, you can avoid the `facet_wrap()` and use this:

```
#Code 2
iris %>% select(-Species) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, it can be done more easily in a one-liner

```
boxplot(iris[-5])
```

[image]

---

Or using `ggboxplot` from `ggpubr`

```
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
iris %>% 
  select(-Species) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  ggboxplot(x = 'name', fill = "name", y = 'value', 
      palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07", "#00FABA"))
```

[image]