# Error: Discrete value supplied to a continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, continuous, geom, discrete

I am writing a code to make custom bland-altman plots. I saw that in one of my plots there was some proportional bias. Therefore I needed to transform my data. I used a transformation of difference/means*100 for my y axis. I tried to use the same custom bland-altman plot function that I wrote for the other variables. However, first I got the error that some variables were non-numeric, hence all the as.numeric() functions... This solved the first problem. My problem now is that R gives me the error:

Error in `train_continuous()`:
! Discrete value supplied to a continuous scale
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I do now uncerstand what is not continuous about my data. Moreover, I set  the x_scale and geom_segements and geom_ribbons in a way that they all run from the very start to the very end of my grid. And I wanted my x axis to be rounded on whole numbers of 5.

There are no NaNs or what so ever in my data. This is my data (PVD_table):

```
PVD_AVA PVD_CCTools
```

1     16.19      6.5602
2     10.76      8.8146
3     17.22     12.0546
4     13.42      9.1943
5      7.44      6.8718
6      9.59      7.6431
7     18.50     11.9803
8     14.19     10.9563
9     12.99      9.7333
10    13.18     11.5637
...
163   18.65      2.6630

My ggplot code:

```
  #### make PVD as percentage ####
    PVD_table <- AVA_CCTools[, c("PVD_small", "PVD_small_CCTools")]
    names(PVD_table) <- c("PVD_AVA", "PVD_CCTools")
    PVD_dif_perc <- (PVD_table[,1] - PVD_table[,2])/((PVD_table[,1]+PVD_table[,2])/2)*100

    #### put means and differences in 2 columns in df
    stats.data <- data.frame(Mean = numeric(length(PVD_table[,1])),Dif = numeric(length(PVD_table[,1])))
    stats.data$Mean[1:length(PVD_table[,1])] <- (PVD_table[,1]+PVD_table[,2])/2
    stats.data$Dif[1:length(stats$differences)] <- PVD_dif_perc

    stats.data$Mean <- as.numeric(stats.data$Mean)
    stats.data$Dif <- as.numeric(stats.data$Dif)

    # make linear model to fit the data
    lin_model_prop <- lm(Dif ~ Mean, data = stats.data)

    summary(lin_model_prop)


    #### make variables for mean bias, upper/lower LoA and their CIs (all in percentage differences)
    se <-               as.numeric(sd(stats.data$Dif)/(sqrt(length(stats.data$Dif))))
    MoE_bias <-         as.numeric(1.96*se)
    MoE_LoA <-          as.numeric(1.96*sqrt(((3 * (sd(stats.data$Dif)^2)) / length(stats.data$Dif))))
    bias <-             as.numeric(mean(stats.data$Dif))
    bias_upperCI <-     as.numeric(bias + MoE_bias)
    bias_lowerCI <-     as.numeric(bias - MoE_bias)
    upperLOA <-         as.numeric(bias + 1.96*sd(stats.data$Dif))
    upperLOA_upperCI <- as.numeric(upperLOA + MoE_LoA)
    upperLOA_lowerCI <- as.numeric(upperLOA - MoE_LoA)
    lowerLOA <-         as.numeric(bias - 1.96*sd(stats.data$Dif))
    lowerLOA_upperCI <- as.numeric(lowerLOA + MoE_LoA)
    lowerLOA_lowerCI <- as.numeric(lowerLOA - MoE_LoA)
    a <- as.numeric(coef(lin_model_prop)[[2]])
    b <- as.numeric(coef(lin_model_prop)[[1]])

       #### plot the proportional bland_altman plot ####
    # round the means at whole numbers of 5 to make x-axis scale
    mult <- 5
    rounded_means <- mult*round(stats.data$Mean[]/mult)
    rounded_means <- as.numeric(rounded_means)

    # set limits for x-axis
    x_lim_low <- min(rounded_means)-5
    x_lim_up <- max(rounded_means)+5

    PVD_prop_bl_plot<- ggplot(stats.data, aes(x = as.numeric(Mean), y = as.numeric(Dif))) +
      geom_point(size = 0.75) +
      geom_abline(intercept = b, slope = a, linetype = "dotted", color = "black") +  # Add regression line
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(min(rounded_means), max(rounded_means)), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      labs(
        x = "Mean",
        y = "AVA 3.2- CCTools / Mean * 100"
      ) +                   #line at mean bias
      geom_segment(x = x_lim_low, xend = x_lim_up, y = bias, yend = bias, linetype = "longdash", color = "black" #BIAS
      )+    #line at lower limit of agreement
      geom_segment(x = x_lim_low, xend = x_lim_up, y = lowerLOA, yend = lowerLOA, linetype = "twodash", color = "black" #upper LoA with CI
      )+                    #line at upper Limit of agreement
      geom_segment(x = x_lim_low, xend = x_lim_up, y = upperLOA, yend =upperLOA, linetype = "twodash", color = "black" #lower LoA with CI
      )+                    # black line at y = 0
      geom_segment(x = x_lim_low, xend = x_lim_up, y = 0, yend = 0, linetype = "solid", color = "black"
      )+                    # regression line
      geom_segment(x = x_lim_low, xend = x_lim_up, y = (x_lim_low*a + b), yend = (x_lim_up*a + b), linetype = "dotdash", color = "black"
      )+      # shade the area of the 95% CI at lower LoA
      geom_ribbon(
        aes(x = rounded_means, xmin = x_lim_low, xmax = x_lim_up, ymin = lowerLOA_lowerCI, ymax = lowerLOA_upperCI),
        fill = "grey", alpha = 0.35
      ) +                   # shade the area of the 95% CI of the Bias
      geom_ribbon(
        aes(x = rounded_means, ymin = bias_lowerCI, ymax = bias_upperCI),
        fill = "grey", alpha = 0.40
      ) +                   # shade the area of the 95% CI at upper LoA
      geom_ribbon(
        aes(x = rounded_means, ymin = upperLOA_lowerCI, ymax = upperLOA_upperCI),
        fill = "grey", alpha = 0.35
      )+
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(color = "1", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic", hjust = 0),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 8),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 8),
        legend.position = "right",
        aspect.ratio = 0.75
      )
```

I tried excuting these lines of code by themself and sometimes for a mysterious reason I do not get an error, but most of the time I get and error. I do not understand what causes this problem and why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: If you sometimes get an error and sometimes don't but you are using the same input, that suggests that your workflow is sloppy and that sometimes you are running extra commands in the console, running lines out of order, or re-running certain some lines that should only be run once.  I would suggest restarting R, starting at the beginning of your script, and being careful to run the lines once each, in order.

Comment: I will say, it's also suspicious how often you are using `as.numeric()` in your code. If you're using a mathematical operation like `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` (or even `sd()` and `sqrt()`), the result should already be numeric. Don't just add `as.numerics()` everywhere hoping they will help. If you're running into problem and you want to make sure something is numeric, use `is.numeric()` to confirm, and if it's not numeric and you think it should be, instead of throwing `as.numeric()` look up in your workflow to track down and solve the problem of **why** it isn't numeric when you think it should be

Comment: The other big irregularity I see in your code is that you are defining all these vectors `#### make variables for mean bias, upper/lower LoA and their CIs (all in percentage differences)` not in any data frame, but then you are plotting them with `ggplot`. `ggplot` really works much more smoothly if all your data is in a data frame. I'd strongly suggest putting things in a data frame for plotting and using `aes()` to define the mappings in each layer, not just the top ggplot() call

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I know I am just a beginner, with horrible coding practice. I wrote this code before I even knew what the aes() did. But one question. If I want to draw a line y = variable. And I have to store that variable in an existing dataframe. Do I have to have to add an extra column to that data frame names 'variable' and fill every row of that column with the value I want that line to y= variable to be at?

Comment: Basically yes. Data frames are rectangular, meaning they have the same number of rows and columns. If you add a column to a data frame, it needs to have a value at each row. (You could use `NA` for missing values.) There are also ways to reshape your data that could potentially simplify your ggplot code - you have 5 `geom_segment` layers, but if you pivoted your data to a long format this could probably be just 1 or 2 layers. [Here's a very very old question where I asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7910594/903061).